# IntelliJ ultimate edition- spring boot plug-in missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ ultimate edition. I don’t see spring boot plug-in . When I search for spring boot I see spring boot assistant. Is Spring boot assistant plug-in same as spring boot plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

- **The Spring Boot plugin:**

Integrates the wizard found at https://start.spring.io/ (to generate Spring projects) into the IDE.

- **Spring Boot Assistant:**

Adds auto-completion support for Spring Boot configuration files (application.yml, etc.).

Comment: I don’t see spring boot plug-in in the market place when I searched. Does that mean it is already installed. I don’t see spring boot configuration template  in my  IntelliJ . Any thoughts?

Comment: You should see *Spring Boot* in the **Installed** tab (found at the top of the settings window) under Plugins. And when you go to `File -> New -> Project...` You should see *Spring Initializr* on the left.

Comment: It should be integrated in the ultimate edition on install. It's one of the perks of having ultimate afaik.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I was able to figure out spring boot configuration.